# Audio Line In bypass system volume

Tags: audio

For a temporary solution to a large problem, I've had to plug my laptop's audio out into the line in of my PC to get audio to play out of my speakers.

This works perfectly fine, however, everything is governed by the system volume of the PC.

*Is there a way to make the Line In volume stay at 100% regardless of the system volume?* Essentially bypassing it completely and relying on the laptop's audio controls to change the volume.

I have Realtek HD Audio Manager installed on the system running Windows 8.1

Comment: what is the large problem? If it is what I think it is, then just use a small line mixer to get audio out of both computers and to the speakers. I found one for around $50.

Comment: Just a cable issue. I have a sound system that supports two line ins. One is a 2.5mm and the other is RCA. My RCA cable is defective and I'm not going to have the chance to get a new AUX cable for a while. It isn't really that large of a problem when it comes down to it :P Just need this as a quick and simple workaround.